# Multilingual Contribution Page

Tags: multilingual

I managed to install CiviCRM with multiple language support (English, Traditional Chinese, and Simplified Chinese).  I can input selected fields in the 3 languages in the contribution page.  However, the URL generated is something like this:

http://xxx.xxxx.com/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=2

It only shows English language.  How can I display other two languages?

I saw a similar question asked back in 2019, but still unanswered.  Great thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your answer.  I've found that respective language page can be displayed by adding a string “&lcMessages = zh_CN" where "zh_CN" is the language code.

The pages of the 3 languages can now be accessed by :

Simplified Chinese:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=2&lcMessages=zh_CN

Traditional Chinse:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=2&lcMessages=zh_TW

English:
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/civicrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=2&lcMessages=en_US

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM picks up the language that is being used by the host CMS. For example, if you are using Drupal in Traditional Chinese then the form in CiviCRM should load in Traditional Chinese as well.

I have not personally used this but there is a Language Switcher extension (https://civicrm.org/blog/ayduns/language-switcher) that might give you more what you are looking for.